# Платяной или плательный?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно говорить: "платяной шкаф" или "плательный"? Первое мне кажется более литературным, но второе явно чаще употребляется.
Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Существительное "платье" имеет два значения: 1. Одежда, носимая поверх белья. Мужское и женское п. Магазин  готового платья.  Верхнее п.  (пальто, шуба, плащ). 2. Женская цельная одежда, надеваемая поверх белья.

От существительного платье образуются три прилагательных: платянОй (к 1-ому значению), плАтельный и платьевОй (ко 2-ому значению).

Соответственно, шкаф может быть только платянОй, есть еще платянАя щетка (для чистки одежды).

Ткань для женского платья - плАтельная или платьевАя (лен,вискоза, джерси, креп, кререпдешин и др.), причем слово "плательный" чаще используется в качестве термина, а "платьевой" относится, скорее,  к нейтральному стилю.

Answer (score 4):

Простите, но в жизни не слышал никаких "плательных шкафов".
Правильно и литературно только "платяной шкаф".

Что до самого слова "плательный", то оно (наряду с "платьевой") используется для указания на "относящийся к платью" (в значении "вид одежды для девочек и женщин"): "плательная ткань" и т.п.